# self.extensionContext!.openURL open app but calls no method

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I am trying to wire the Today extensions to my app by using the following piece of code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selection=busCollection[indexPath.row];
    let palina=selection?.palina;
    let urlAsString = "widget://pathto/" + "\(palina)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)
    self.extensionContext!.openURL(url!, completionHandler: { (success: Bool) -> Void in
            print("completed")
        }
    )
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

Yet activating that method correctly opens my app but launches it in the standard way without calling:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
```

What may be the issue? Of course I registered my widget on the info.plist file, otherwise the app would probably not have been even opened.

Comment: Did you implement the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method in your AppDelegate?

Comment: Sure, even if I use it for receiving requests for directions. The source I read suggested it was: -(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url to be called by the extension.
At any rate, neither of them is called as I put breakpoints in each of them, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did end up calling the delegate method.